# Copying text from many div to many input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with many product listed. Each of those products is inside a div and has a form like this:

```
<form class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="">
    <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button">Add to Cart</button>
</form>
```

As you can see the value of add-to-cart is missing.

In the same div where the form is, we have an other div like this that contains the ID of the product (for instance IDPRODUCT), that needs to go inside the value:

```
<div class="vc_gitem-woocommerce vc_gitem-woocommerce-product-id hideidfromcart vc_gitem-align-left">IDPRODUCT</div>
```

I need a javascript function that on document ready(?) or onmouseover the div searches for the value inside the div, for instance IDPRODUCT, and copy this value into the value of the input name="add-to-cart"

Of course for each of those different divs there should be the proper IDPRODUCT.

Here is one JSFiddle I tried but it doesn't seem to work:[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9kj8521e/)

Any idea of how to solve this?
Thank you so much

Comment: can you share website link? also for clearance you want if someone clicks to add to cart it should be got cart page with product added to the basket hiddenly?

Comment: http://new.bioitalia.it/legumi-e-cereali/ this is the page, the basket is showed to the user, it won't be hidden. Just the id of the product is hidden because it makes no sense to display it.

Comment: please make clear that  you want if someone clicks to add to cart it should be got cart page with product added to the basket hiddenly

Comment: yes, of course, but that's what happens when the id is correctly set into the input, so that's the only thing that I need :)

Comment: you cannot do that if you set id it will work for only one product, it will work like this http://new.bioitalia.it/pronti/  , also  if you pass id in the coding file then it will work assign a template to the category page and add there your form into code part and then the id will be using something like this $id

Comment: yes I know that if I always put the same id it won't work. I want to know how can I do this in javascript or if there is a way of adding a parameter into a shortcode with VisualComposer

Comment: https://nicola.blog/2015/05/04/add-the-quantity-field-to-the-add_to_cart-shortcode/   check it it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The full Example again

```js
$('.cart-add-wrapper').each(function(){
    var id = $(this).find('.vc_gitem-woocommerce-product-id').text();
    $(this).find('input[name=add-to-cart]').val(id);
    console.log("id", id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart-add-wrapper">
    <form class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="">
        <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button">Add to Cart</button>
    </form>
    <div class="vc_gitem-woocommerce vc_gitem-woocommerce-product-id hideidfromcart vc_gitem-align-left">4321</div>
</div>
<div class="cart-add-wrapper">
    <form class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="">
        <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button">Add to Cart</button>
    </form>
    <div class="vc_gitem-woocommerce vc_gitem-woocommerce-product-id hideidfromcart vc_gitem-align-left">1234</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you do a Jsfiddle please? I'm testing it but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: No I cant. Check your html structure. If it looks quite different please Update your question to make clear what your problem ist about. And no, I wont follow your link

Comment: I made a new file using exactly your code (even for the structure), so that's how it looks like and that's why I said it doesn't seem to work

Comment: so you cold make the js fiddle your self and update the question

Comment: added jsfiddle to my question

Comment: You need to activate jquery in the jsfiddle ;)

Comment: see my example - that one works. replace line two with my line two in js part